# Fiat Uno 1.0 cylinder head valves

Tags: engine, cylinder, cylinder-head

I would like to know how to remove the valves from the cylinder head.

Comment: With an [appropriate tool](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Valve-Spring-Compressor-Pincer-Tool-C-Style-Z-Cylinder-Head-Off-Removal-/302014484044), I guess. I'm fairly certain a quick Youtube search will provide sufficient guidance.

Comment: Possible sometimes without a special tool - I put a spacer under the valve head and pushed down on the valve spring with a ring spanner to remove the collets - worked fine.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You will need to be **A LOT** more specific than that. Use the [edit] feature to add details of what you have researched, where you are at in the process of removing them and where you have gotten stuck. We will try to help from there.